# Slightly edit/scupt the rigged character in Zbrush without loosing weights

Tags: rigging

I have a character in Blender with a complete rig, I want to sculpt it slightly in Zbrush, but then I need somehow transfer all weight into edited/sculpted model.

What is the best way to do it? The polygon count will remain the same.

Comment: If you only need to slightly tweak the character using sculpting tools why not just use the ones already in Blender?

Comment: I need to use Morph brush and Project tools, I can't find the alternatives in Blender, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, maybe you'll find this post useful, you can try using a Data Transfer modifier to generate the vertex groups on your re-imported mesh.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34719718/transferring-rig-weights-from-one-mesh-to-another-in-blender-2-76/34760742#34760742

Comment: I wonder, maybe I can just morph somehow original mesh to edited mesh, vertex count is the same, so I think vertex numbers/IDs will match too, right?

Comment: This may require some trial and error but if the imported mesh has the same topology you may be able to just add it as a shape key somehow.